# Jquery grep and filtering against other array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to ask, how can i filter data using Jquery and grep?

Some example code:

```
var arr = ['11','21']

obj = $.grep(obj, function (element, index) {
        return element.Id == 11;
    });
```

This will return obj data with id of 11.
But, how can i retrieve data from obj, when Id will be like arr array ?

So i wanted, to have obj with properties equal to Id 11 and 21 ?

Thank You.

Comment: So it is like an or conditional?  Id == arr[0] || Id == arr[1] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
var arr = ['11', '21']

obj = $.grep(obj, function (element, index) {
    return arr.indexOf(element.Id + '') > -1;//the + '' is used since the array has string values
    //or $.inArray(element.Id + '', arr) > -1
});
```

- [$.inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JavaScript's own native [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to [achieve the same result](http://jsfiddle.net/rbwrqw44/):

```
var arr = obj.filter(function (el) {
    return arr.map(Number).indexOf(el.Id) > -1;
});
```